# How do I adapt my ggplot code so that it I can plot 3 or more date frames on one graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I have 3 dataframes, DF1, DF2 and DF3. I want to plot all the dataframes on one graph. How do I adapt my ggplot code so that I can plot 3 or more date frames on one graph?

```
Time1 <- c("10:11:11", "11:30:30", "12:55:00", "14:35:30", "15:06:01", 
"16:15:30"))

Measurement1 <- c("15", "18", "16", "17", "14", "15")

DF1 <- data.frame(Time1, Measurement1)

Time2 <- c("10:11:11", "11:30:30", "12:55:00", "14:35:30", "15:06:01", 
"16:15:30"))

Measurement2 <- c("20", "24", "27", "25", "26", "27")

DF2 <- data.frame(Time2, Measurement2)

Time3 <- c("10:11:11", "11:30:30", "12:55:00", "14:35:30", "15:06:01", 
"16:15:30"))

Measurement3 <- c("30", "32", "34", "31", "35", "33")

DF3 <- data.frame(Time3, Measurement3)
```

ggplot code below;

```
Day1plot <- ggplot(DF1, aes(Time1, Measurement1, group = 1))+geom_point() +
geom_line() +
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
ggtitle('XD2 Consumption readings (Sun 3rd Of June 2018)') +
xlab('Times') +
ylab('kWh') + 
theme_bw() +
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

Day1plot + theme(axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold", colour="black", 
size=10),axis.text.x  = element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.5, size=10))
```

Comment: Your reproducible example has some errors so won't run. You can look at `cowplot::plot_grid` or, if your data each contains the same variables, you can combine and use `facet_wrap`.

Comment: a) your vectors have different length and dataframes cannot be created. b) you expect to plot the other 2 datasets as lines with a different colour? Something else?

Comment: @Chris Sorry I dont understand what your saying. Can you elloborate?

Comment: @AntoniosK I have made sure my vectors have the same length now. And yes I would like the other 2 datasets as lines with different colours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution combines your datasets and creates an dataset identifier column, so you know which rows belong to which dataset. Also, this identifier will be used as a grouping variable for your plot:

**Example data**

```
Time1 <- c("10:11:11", "11:30:30", "12:55:00", "14:35:30", "15:06:01", "16:15:30")
Measurement1 <- c("15", "18", "16", "17", "14", "15")
DF1 <- data.frame(Time1, Measurement1)

Time2 <- c("10:11:11", "11:30:30", "12:55:00", "14:35:30", "15:06:01", "16:15:30")
Measurement2 <- c("20", "24", "27", "25", "26", "27")
DF2 <- data.frame(Time2, Measurement2)

Time3 <- c("10:11:11", "11:30:30", "12:55:00", "14:35:30", "15:06:01", "16:15:30")
Measurement3 <- c("30", "32", "34", "31", "35", "33")
DF3 <- data.frame(Time3, Measurement3)
```

**Code**

```
library(tidyverse)

# update datasets in order to be able to be combined 
DF1 = DF1 %>% set_names("Time", "Measurement") %>% mutate(group = "DF1") 
DF2 = DF2 %>% set_names("Time", "Measurement") %>% mutate(group = "DF2") 
DF3 = DF3 %>% set_names("Time", "Measurement") %>% mutate(group = "DF3") 

# bind rows
DF = rbind(DF1, DF2, DF3)

# plot the big dataset using a grouping variable
ggplot(DF, aes(Time, Measurement, col = group, group = group))+
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  ggtitle('XD2 Consumption readings (Sun 3rd Of June 2018)') +
  xlab('Times') +
  ylab('kWh') + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+ 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold", colour="black", 
                                    size=10),axis.text.x  = element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.5, size=10))
```

[image]

Comment: You can shorten the code a bit with `DF = map_df(list(DF1=DF1, DF2=DF2, DF3=DF3), ~ .x %>% set_names("Time", "Measurement"), .id="group")`.

Comment: @AntoniosK Thank you. Lastly, just to help me understand, what does the following collection of symbols mean in the code? "%>%" Also what does mutate mean in this case?

Comment: Those are based on `dplyr` package (part of `tidyverse` package). `mutate` creates a new variable, or updates a current one and `%>%` is way to combine/connect commands to be executed one after the other.

Comment: [This tutorial](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html) on `dplyr` and the `%>%` (pipe) operator may be helpful.